# Return Specific Row From DB

Tags: php, html, database

I have multiple links on a page where each link is suppose to return a specific row of data from a database. When the link is clicked, the user is forwarded to another page where the info associated with that link is displayed. Here is the code:

```
//db connection: (using xampp)
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('db_name');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_input";
$records = mysql_query($sql);

//code:
<div>
$open_report = mtsql_fetch_assoc($records);
    echo "Error Report# {$open_report['id']};
    echo "<p>" .$open_report['comments'] . "</p>";
</div>
```

The problem is it always returns the same row of data. Each row in the db is associated with a link and when that link is clicked I want to return the associated row of data in the db. I think it may have to do with this line: $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_input"; but I'm not sure how to fix it. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: just saw a typo: should read: $open_report = mysql_fetch_assoc($records); echo "Error report# {$open_report['id']}";

Comment: At the moment, you're selecting all (*) columns from the `user_input` table. You're not including a `where` condition to specify which rows. Your links should contain unique identifiers for the row they point towards so you can include them in the SQL query and pick out a certain row.

Comment: So how do I specify a row when the row is dependant on what link the user clicks?

Answer (score 0):

I have restructured my answer to give it a better flow. I also noticed you are using mysql_ not mysqli_ . You need to use mysqli_ as mysql is depreciated.

EDIT: This would be the page that displays all the error reports. You would want to output them in the form of a hyperlink that passes a GET parameter to the page that shows the details.

```
$sql = "SELECT ID, Description, etc, etc  from reports";
$open_reports = mysqli_query($sql);

//error check here as well if ANY results were returned
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($open_reports, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  echo '<a href="detailspage.php?id=' . $open_reports['ID'] . '">'' . $open_reports['Description'] . '</a>';
}
```

This will give you links that look like

`detailspage.php?id=1`
 `detailspage.php?id=2`
etc...

On the "detailspage.php" You can capture that ID and display dynamic information on that same page.

```
if (isset($_GET['ID'])){
  $sql = "Select * from user_input where ID='" . $_GET['id'] . "'";
  $records = mysqli_query($sql)

  while($open_report = mysqli_fetch_array($records, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo "Error Report# " . $open_report['id'] . "<br/>";
        echo "<p>" .$open_report['comments'] . "</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I've used a loop to display some info in the database on one page. On that page I've applied a link to all error reports return from the db. When an error report link is clicked I want to display info associated with that error report on another page. If I assign an ID to each link will I be able to reference that ID on another page and use the query you've suggested?

Comment: Ok. Can I include a $variable in a mysql Query?

Comment: Yes, you can include a $variable in a mysql query.

Comment: Thank you. I've applied the modifications as you've suggested and it works like a charm, however I have a question. Why did you choose to use a while loop for the "details.php" page. I mean I have my assumptions but I would like to be clear as to why you choose to do so.

Comment: Your result is actually an array. So you could possible have more than 1 record come back from the database. If this was the case, it would print out all the results.